# I am unable to digitally resign my APK file using the Resign JAR app. Error message is seen

Tags: android, jar

After deleting the META-INF folder in my test APK file dragging and dropping it into the Re-sign JAR file, I see an error message:

```
"Error - Cannot run program "D:\work\android-sdks\platform-tools/tools/zipalign":CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"
```

Seems I might be going wrong with the path setting. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK has changed `zipalign` path. In previous version it was on

```
<android-sdk>\tools\zipalign
```

now it is inside a specific version of build tool, for example

```
<android-sdk>\build-tools\22.0.1\zipalign
```

re-sign.jar search for `zipalign` in the old path. Try to copy `zipalign` executable from the last build tool you have to the `tools` directory

Comment: What is the value of your ANDROID_HOME environment variable?